# Mixed Content removal from WordPress, can someone please help me with the details on how to fix it

Tags: content

How do I remove mixed content in WordPress,(I want to put the green padlock that shows a website is secure on my website, but mixed content is preventing me from getting it right) Please I want the steps detailed. Thank you

Comment: Please let me know what do you mean by mixed content?

Comment: He means when a site has been migrated to https, you will get mixed content warnings.   The question is too broad as it depends on the assets, theme and plugins a particular site is using and the users ability.   Of course, there is a plugin but thats not the route id personally recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SSL Insecure Content Fixer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) plugin. Select *Simple* option in its settings, first. Move to next option, if it does not fix mixed content completely. Repeat this, with next option, until all is fixed.